# How can I filter by read depth using vcftools?

Tags: vcftools

I am trying to build a workflow to analyse my scRNA-seq data. I am using a combination of GATK and samtools, vcftools, bcftools. I would like to filter my .vcf file such that it removes all entries that have fewer than 10 reads. It looks like vcftools can be used for this. My code is:

`vcftools --vcf "$fn" --out "$fn"_dp10 --minDP 10 --recode --recode-INFO-all`

However, it does not filter out anything. Any thoughts on this?

Kind regards
Cora

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer!
I had to use `--mean-minDP` instead of `--minDP`.

Kind regards
Cora

Comment: VCFtools (v0.1.17) `Error: Unknown option: --mean-minDP`

Answer (score 0):

One source of `--minDP` not working is a parsing bug that emits a warning, but does not error.

> https://github.com/vcftools/vcftools/issues/134